# How do I cut a blooming onion?

Tags: knife-skills, onions

A blooming onion is a deep fried onion which opens up during frying to resemble a flower.

Obviously, I start with a giant onion. How do I cut it?

Comment: Recipe requests are off-topic, so I adjusted your title to reflect the technique.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Slice off 1/2" of the top of the onion (opposite the root)
- Place onion root side up, and make slices all the way through, staying at least 1/2" away from the root
- Flip it over and spread apart the leaves

This is best described with [images](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes-and-cooking/how-to-slice-a-bloominrsquo-onion/pictures/index.html).

Alternatively, if you're willing to drop a few hundred dollars, you can buy a bloomin' onion cutter. This is what restaurants use. There are cheaper alternatives, but I can't vouch for their quality or ease of use.

Comment: great link. You're right, the pictures make your instructions much more clear.